# Grails force controller download file

Tags: grails, groovy

I have following code :

```
def getMyFile(){


    File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.xsl")

    try{

        response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${myFile.name}"
        response.contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(myFile )
        response.outputStream << myFile .bytes
        response.outputStream.flush()
    }

    catch (e){
        println(e.message)
    }

}
```

When accessing this controller action, I want the browser to download the excel file.

The code does not create any errors in the console, but the file is not downloaded correctly.

Comment: Did you try setting the content length. response.setContentLength(...)

Answer (score 5):

Here's something that works for me for a lot of file types

```
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myFileName\"")
        response.outputStream << myFile.newInputStream()
        return
```